# Can't connect to Postgres container with Docker Compose from Sequelize

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, sequelize.js

I can't connect to the default Postgres image from a separate docker service running node & Sequelize.

I'm assuming that my setup of the container is not correct and also perhaps my connection info is incorrect too because I when I run `docker-compose --build` I cannot connect to my database using the connection info:

```
Host: 0.0.0.0
Port: 5432
User: guy
Password: password
Database: engauge
```

The error message is

```
Unable to connect to the database: { SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:5432
at /usr/src/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js:98:20
```

I am running with a YML file that looks like this

```
version: '2' # specify docker-compose version

# Define the services/containers to be run
services:
  web: # name of the first service
    build: . # specify the directory of the Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000" # specify port forewarding
    links:
      - database
  database: # name of the third service
    image: postgres # specify image to build container from
    ports:
      - "5432:5432" # specify port forewarding
    environment:
         - POSTGRES_USER:'guy'
         - POSTGRES_PASSWORD:'password'
         - POSTGRES_DB:'engauge'
```

And my connection from within my web service looks like this

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize('postgresql://guy:password@0.0.0.0/engauge');
```

Comment: You can only listen on 0.0.0.0, you cannot connect to it. Have you tried 127.0.0.1? (Or whatever the container's IP address is. )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The 0.0.0.0 is the listening address, it's used to listen on all interfaces and isn't an IP that you connect to. In your connect string, specify the service name for the hostname to connect to, in your case `database`.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll also add that I had to clear the existing volumes and containers after making this change for them to take effect.

Comment: I don't see any volumes listed above. With compose, you can just run `docker-compose up -d` to apply new container configs. It's usually smart enough to see which have changed settings and recreate the necessary containers.